# My images take forever to load

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have site I am working on and the images take forever to load, they are coming from the server, and are being uploaded using php upload, the images being uploaded ar 1212x2564 or similar

here is the html img attribute I am using

```
<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image'] ?>" width="500" />
```

My site is http://www.willruppelglass.com/

why is it taking forever for my images to load?

Comment: You pretty much answered it yourself with `"the images being uploaded ar 1212x2564 or similar"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use server-side image processing to scale them down to an acceptable size for the web.

http://www.zeronese.net/knowledge-base/articles/article-1060.html

Comment: This answer assumes that there's a `<form>` being used to upload the images though. It appears to be a personal website that (I would guess) he's uploading images to, either over FTP or using some sort of interface like cPanel.

Comment: Its just an example for serverside image processing. The same or similar technique can be used without and upload field.

Comment: Found this...seems to work fine thus far http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Answer (score 3):

The images are enormous, and are being downloaded at their original resolution. Giving the image a specific width either as an HTML parameter or using CSS will only stretch/shrink the original image, it **will not** change the resolution or file size for you.

To speed up the loading, you should create thumbnail versions of your images, whose actual resolution is 500px.

If you let us know what OS you're using, we can recommend tools for creating the thumbnails.

Comment: How would I create thumbnail versions of my images?

Comment: Would you like to create them on your server, or on a separate machine then upload them separately? What operating systems do you have available in both cases?

Comment: I have windows 7, and Mac the latest one. I guess I would like it if the user uploads an image and reszies it and uploads it to the server.

Comment: Are you uploading all the images yourself, or are multiple users uploading images?

Comment: the person I made the website for is

Comment: You can either make it easy for that person and use Fresheyeball's answer to perform some server-side processing and automatically create thumbnail versions of the images when they're uploaded, or you can make it difficult for that person (and easy for yourself) and have him create thumbnail versions of his images and upload those along with the originals.

Answer (score 3):

Those images are huge, they need to be drastically reduced in size if you expect them to load in a reasonable amount of time.

You can use [WebResizer](http://www.webresizer.com/) to help you out with this for free or use your favorite graphics editing program.

Answer (score 1):

if  you a new to these thing sometimes it is worth using something like wordpress as this contains automatic image resizing. You can define the size of images you want to use in certain areas and wp will create an image of the correct site even if you upload the original full size image. Obviously this require some configuration but it might easier than trying to build an image resizer from scratch using php.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are way too big. I mean, they aren't just a little big, they are way too big. I never recommend anything bigger than 1600px max.